# Display Full GridLines .NET DataGridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

By default, the background of a `DataGridView` is a solid color.  The gridlines stop at the end of the grid of actual data leaving an ugly void in the remaining space of the `DataGridView`.

A perfect example of what I want is the gridlines viewed in Microsoft Excel.

How can I continue the gridlines past the datagrid itself to fill the `DataGridView`?

**Note:** VB.NET preferred, C# answers okay

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking but if you want a grid to take up all the space in your view you can set the DockStyle of the grid control to fill.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. DataGridView is more similar to what you would see in MS Access than Excel (I think MSAcces has the "ugly" background too).

Comment: Use firebug to get the datagrid styled how you want it, then figure out how to apply those styles to the datagridview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the DataGridView.CellPainting event, because the DataGridView doesn't support this out-of-the-box.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2d91bed2-68e9-41f3-9f6e-73de193640e8/

Also, if you want the background color to be the same as grid's change it to white or something...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to set the `.AutoSizeMode` of one or more columns to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill`. This ensures the columns exactly fill the area of the grid, with no void.

This may not be entirely the effect you want to achieve though.

Comment: Yup, this trivially solves it.  Just making the grid smaller would do it too.